Does navigating between client components in Nuxt trigger a request to the server?
In nextjs when navigating between client components after already having the app loaded, it still triggers a request to the server which sends back a basic html file of the page requested.
I want to know if the same happens with nuxt, lets say i have this example:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    // Landing page
    '/': { prerender: true },
    //dashboard
    '/app/**': { ssr: false }
  }
})

when navigating between
 /app/users 

and
/app/products 

for example, does it happen 100% on the client, or does it trigger a request to Nuxt server for the /app/products route?
i tried setting up this example and checking the network tab, but i'm not sure if it functions differently when in a different env like production.

No, once the app is hydrated you do not reach out the server for the rendering part again. You can meanwhile send a request back to the server with the server directory.
